# Distribute Excel workbook powered by web add-in (office.js)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have a complex Excel workbook that I intend to automate using the new office.js add-in. As I understand from documentation, we should publish a manifest containing the location of the source code of the add-in's js. This add-in also has custom ribbon commands and a task pane.

In my use case, this complex workbook contains a lot of data, formulas, pivots and charts. I wouldn't want to recreate everything from scratch on the first execution of the add-in.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to publish somewhere this workbook and ask the user to install the add-in?
2. How can I ship the workbook with the manifest inside of it? I would expect the same experience we have on VSTO - an excel file with some sort of "macros" or "custom areas" containing the automation information.
3. Is it possible to restrict the add-in to this specific document? This would be document-level customization in this use case.

Comment: 1. No. 2. You can't. 3. No. For your options about publishing an add-in, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish.

Comment: I have extensively studied the documentation. But I couldn't find anything related to document-level customizations. It seems to be only application-wide customizations for now. I couldn't find anything on the roadmap specific to document-level customizations as well. Thanks for your reply so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest spending some more time reading up on wed add-ins, you clearly have a good understanding of previous incarnations of Excel add-ins, however web add-ins bring a big shift from this.

Answers to your queries:

1 - The add-in is effectively a static web application and is considered separate to the worksheet.

2 - Web add-ins are hosted on a webserver or similar.  We are hosting within AWS S3 fronted by API gateway, but MS would steer you towards an Azure solution.

3 - If you really needed to, if you got creative you could restrict functions in the add-in when certain conditions are met in the worksheet.

Comment: If number 3 is true, I can easily distribute the workbook, ask the user to install the plugin from the store and ensure the plugin only kicks in when a workbook with certain internal properties are found.  Great. But, I have a concern: can we unload/remove the ribbon customization for other documents? This would be sufficient for my use case.

Comment: Regarding worksheet conditions, can be these conditions stored in custom parts of the document? Are they supported by offfice.js as well?

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles You can add customxml data to documents. You can also manipulate the ribbon as well. You can also have an add-in "register" itself to a document. For dev, I have a document that automatically loads my add-in and begins running a function to speed up the process of clicking buttons to start/test my changes.